# Fast arbitrary decomposition of a positive-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity, matrix-decomposition

Given a positive-definite $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, my goal is to present it as a product of the form $\mathbf{H^TH}$, where $\mathbf{H}$ is an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix.

Cholesky decomposition does this with $\mathbf{H}$ upper-triangular. However, its complexity is of the order $O(n^3)$. The question is whether it is possible to do this quicker if we remove all the constraints on $\mathbf{H}$.

Comment: No. The Cholesky factorization is actually the quickest square root you can compute (in a pure flop count sense). The triangular nature of Cholesky isn't a _constraint_ in the sense you seem to think; it's just a natural consequence of the attempt to design an efficient algorithm.

Comment: That said, just as there are fast sub-$n^3$ methods for matrix multiplication (e.g., Strassen, Winograd), there are fast sub-$n^3$ methods for Cholesky factorization as well.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I'm not sure if these "fast sub-$n^3$ methods" are faster in practice though. From what I understood, the current architecture of computers is so that addition and multiplication have almost the same costs and so methods based on Strassen are not practically faster.

Comment: Agreed, @Surb. My primary point is that Cholesky is the best you're going to do.

Comment: @MichaelGrant While, I tend to believe you, I'd love to see a proof of that. For instance, it is not crystal clear to me why a Babylonian method for computing the square root $A^{1/2}$ with a good starting point would not be faster.

Comment: @Surb what is the complexity of an individual iteration of the Babylonian method?

Comment: It seems indeed to be at least $O(n^3)$. I am intrigued because in his book on functions of matrices, Higham mention the real Schur method for computing $A^{1/2}$ with a total complexity of $28/3 n^3$. He then discuss Babylonian method and its generalizations but does not explicitly give a total cost. I unfortunately don't have the time right now to read the whole chapter. However, I admit that it seems unlikely that the constant in $O(n^3)$ can be made smaller than 1/3 for these methods.